# how to chain functions with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to make the clickable link active ( the border and the link `a` color). the border is switching on the clicked links but the color of the link is not changing. i want the active link to be yellow `#eab000`(the border and link `a` color) . and the non active links to be black `404040`(the border and link `a` color)

[SEE MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hpn8pjae/)

I was trying

```
  $('ul li').first().css({
   'border':'1px solid #eab000',
  }).find('a').css({
   'color':'#eab000'
  });

  $('ul li').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   $(this).css({
    'border':'1px solid #eab000',
   }).siblings('li').css({
    'border':'none',
   }).find('a').css({
    'color':'#eab000'
   });

 });
```

Comment: i think the issue is that you are using 
.find('a') which is turning all your links yellow, its applying that CSS to all the anchors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So how about changing the activeItem to be on the li that has been clicked?

```
  $('ul li').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).siblings().removeClass("activeItem");
      $(this).addClass("activeItem");
  });
```

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ug3tLg84/1/)

Or even better, if you're in to chaining:

```
  $('ul li').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).addClass("activeItem").siblings().removeClass("activeItem");
  });
```

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ug3tLg84/2/)

I should point out that I've added the following CSS:

```
ul li.activeItem
{
    border: 1px solid #eab000;
}
ul li.activeItem a
{
    color:#eab000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
$('ul li').first().css({
    'border':'1px solid #eab000',
  }).find('a').css({
    'color':'#eab000'
  });

  $('ul li').on('click',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      $(this).css({
        'border':'1px solid #eab000',
      }).find('a').css({
          'color' : '#eab000'
      }).parent().siblings('li').css({
        'border':'none',
      }).find('a').css({
        'color':'#404040'
      });

  });
```

You were using ".siblings" for the "inactive" links and then setting their anchor colours to your active colour. By setting the anchor before using "siblings" and then using "parent", you keep at a consistent level within the chain.

See your fiddle, fixed, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hpn8pjae/4/)

However, the usage of specific colours within your code makes this kind of structure a bit brittle. Add/remove class as shown in the other examples is a more sustainable solution.

Comment: I am downvoting for your lack of ability in following simple specifications

Answer (score 1):

Think about what comes out of each method and therefore what is going into the next :

`css` = out: the same as in, so ignored for clarity

`this` = out: the `li` clicked 
`siblings` = in: li, out: the other `li`s of the `li` clicked
`find` = in: the other `li`s, out: all `a`s under the other `li`s

if you moved the `find` up:

```
$(this).css({
 'border':'1px solid #eab000',
}).find('a').css({
 'color':'#eab000'
}).siblings('li').css({
 'border':'none',
});
```

to match the `.first` then the a will work, but the siblings won't as now:

`this` = out: the `li` clicked 
`find` = in: the `li` clicked, out: all `a`s under the clicked `li`
`siblings` = in: the 'a', out: nothing (assumed)

so ideally, before the siblings you want some way to "cancel" the previous `find`, luckily jquery has just this: [.end()](https://api.jquery.com/end/)

You can apply this to either the original (find `a` then go back to find siblings) or (find siblings then go back to find `a`)

Here it is with the missing extra colour change

```
$(this).css({
 'border':'1px solid #eab000',
}).find('a').css({
 'color':'#eab000'
})
.end()
.siblings('li').css({
 'border':'none',
}).find('a').css({
 'color':'#404040'
});
```