# How to remove a class from all sublings using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add an 'active' class of clicked `<li>` link and remove all 'active' class from siblings.

I tried as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#account-settings').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
 });
});
```

It adds 'active' class to clicked item but not remove 'active' from siblings.

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#account-settings').on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active" id="account-overview">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
      <i class="icon-home"></i> Overview </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="account-settings">
      <i class="icon-settings"></i> Account Settings </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=" /demo-home19/resellers/logout">
      <i class="icon-settings"></i> Logout </a>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context...

Comment: I removed Same ID and Edited my question accordingly

Comment: I've literally just answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33735186/how-to-chain-functions-with-jquery/33735340 Are you guys in the same class?

Comment: You are binding the click to the anchor so you have no siblings which is why your jquery is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
  $('#account-settings').on('click',function(){
       var li = $(this).parent('li')
        li.parent().find('li').removeClass('active');
        li.addClass('active');

     });
```

or:

```
 $('#account-settings').on('click',function(){
       var li = $(this).parent('li')
        li.siblings().removeClass('active');
        li.addClass('active');

     });
```

or

```
 $('#account-settings').on('click',function(){
       $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of id `#account-settings`

```
$('ul li').on('click',function(){....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try doing

```
$('.nav').children('li').on('click',function(){
  $('.nav').children('li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```